# What is the meaning of "a POST request also has $_GET parameters"

Tags: php, post, get

Hi i am looking at differences between `$_GET` and `$_POST` methods , i came across some articles that says

- A POST request also has $_GET parameters
- So a POST request is a superset of a GET request; you can use $_GET in a POST request, and it may even make sense to have
  parameters with the same name in $_POST and $_GET that mean different
  things.

[When should I use GET or POST method? What's the difference between them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504947/when-should-i-use-get-or-post-method-whats-the-difference-between-them)

http://www.sitepoint.com/on-get-and-post/

And there is an example also

> For example, let's say you have a form for editing an article. The
>   article-id may be in the query string (and, so, available through
>   $_GET['id']), but let's say that you want to change the article-id.
>   The new id may then be present in the request body ($_POST['id']).

so how can we use `$_GET['id'] and $_POST['id']` at the same time  , confusing .
Please explain this with a simple example . so everyone including me , who does not understand this can understand well .

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: look into `$_REQUEST`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest way to understand this is that `$_GET` is simply badly named. All it actually represents is the values of "query string" parameters parsed from the part of a URL after a `?`. Since every request has a URL, whatever type it is, any request can populate `$_GET`.

`$_POST`, on the other hand, is populated only for POST requests, and even then only those whose request body is in a particular format.

When you use `method=get` in HTML, the browser just creates a URL based on the form data, and asks for that URL with a GET request the same as you typing it into the address bar. With `method=post`, the form data is sent separately from the URL, but the URL might still contain a `?` and a query string.

Answer (score 4):

I'll explain to you by using an example:

```
<form method='post' action='edit-article.php?article_id=3'>
    <label for='article_name'>Article name:</label>
    <input type='text' name='article_name' value='' />
    <input type='submit' name='edit' value='Change article name' />
</form>
```

When you press submit you will be redirected to *edit-article.php?article_id=3*

Here you will have the following variables set:
`$_GET['article_id']` (from url), `$_POST['article_name']`(from form) and `$_POST['edit']` (the submit button, also via form)

Answer (score 1):

Think of it like this. You have two completely different arrays:

```
$A = array();
$B = array();
```

Now you can write this piece of code:

```
$A['id'] = 8;
$B['id'] = 5;
```

The above code is completely valid. These are different arrays, they just happen to have the same keys with different values assigned to them.

`$_GET` and `$_POST` are different variables. Everything you write into the url query will show up in the $_GET variable, evrerything you send via POST will end up in `$_POST`. So you can set the same key in the URL query and in the POST data.

However, `$_REQUEST` holds the data of `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE`. If you have the same keys in `$_POST` and `$_GET` we can assume, that `$_REQUEST` will hold only one of the values. I actually do not know, which value will be saved in `$_REQUEST` and I hope someone else knows the answer to that, because I am very curious about that.