# Display entries from 2 drop down menus in another page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I want to display the entered fields from 2 drop down menus in another page.

Code:

```
<form action="home/show" method="post">
<p>Vendor:</p>
<select id="v" name="v">
    <% @vendors.each do |vendor| %>
        <option value=<%= vendor.id%>><%= vendor.name%></option>
    <% end %>
<select>

<p>Retailer:</p>
<select id="r" name="r">
    <% @retailers.each do |retailer| %>
        <option value=<%= retailer.id%>><%= retailer.name%></option>
    <% end %>
<select>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Display page:

```
Vendor: <?php echo $_POST["v"]; ?>
Retailer: <?php echo $_POST["r"]; ?>
```

The page loads but the fields are empty

Comment: In addition to the answers, always wrap option values inside double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`, like this:

```
Vendor: <?php echo $_POST["v"]; ?>
Retailer: <?php echo $_POST["r"]; ?>
```

The variables are submitted as `POST`-variables, as indicated by the form's submit method (`method="post"`). And they should be, don't use `GET` to submit forms. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504947/when-should-i-use-get-or-post-method-whats-the-difference-between-them) for more information.

Comment: still getting empty after switching to POST, am I calling the drop menus incorrectly with ["v"]?

Comment: Does the `home/show` in the `action` resolve to the page where you are trying to display the variables?

Answer (score 1):

You have use `method="post"` on your form, but are using `$_GET` in your php, you need to use `$_POST`