# How to create separate python script for uploading data into ndb

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Can anyone guide me towards the right direction as to where I should place a script solely for loading data into ndb. As I wish to upload all data into the gae ndb so that the application could perform query on it.

Right now, the loading of data is in my application. I wish to placed it separately from the main application.

Should it be edited in the yaml file?

**EDITED**

This is a snippet of the entity and the handler to upload the data into GAE ndb.
I wish to placed this chunk of code separately from my main application .py. Reason being the uploading of this data won't be done frequently and to keep the codes in the main application "cleaner".

```
class TagTrend_refine(ndb.Model):
    tag = ndb.StringProperty()
    trendData = ndb.BlobProperty(compressed=True)

class MigrateData(webapp2.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
        listOfEntities = []
        f = open("tagTrend_refine.txt")
        lines = f.readlines()
        f.close()
        for line in lines:
            temp = line.strip().split("\t")
            data = TagTrend_refine(
                tag = temp[0],
                trendData = temp[1]
            )
        listOfEntities.append(data)
        ndb.put_multi(listOfEntities)
```

For example if I placed the above code in a file called dataLoader.py, where should I call this script to invoke?

In app.yaml alongside my main application(knowledgeGraph.application)?

```
- url: /.*
script: knowledgeGraph.application
```

Comment: Where do you intend your "add-on script" to run? If on App Engine, then yes, it needs to be in app.yaml (which can have multiple handlers, it doesn't force them all into `main.app` -- in some cases you could put it in a separate module); if on your machine or some other computer, as the word "upload" suggests, then, no, it shouldn't be in app.yaml nor any GAE module's yaml (they're all for code to run in GAE!). Please edit your Q to provide *MUCH*, *MUCH* more and clearer detail of your use case, and we'll be glad to help!

Comment: @AlexMartelli thanks for the reply, I have added the details in the question.

Comment: One thing to consider, if you don't plan to do this often and don't have hundreds of thousands of entities, don't bother to create a handler.  Run the upload code via remote_api shell. It won't be as fast but can run for essentially forever (ie no 60 second deadline or having to create tasks) and no additional code to deploy, but does imply developer access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show us the `application` object (no doubt a WSGI app) in your `knowledge.py` module, so I can't know what URL you want to serve with the `MigrateData` handler -- I'll just guess it's something like `/migratedata`.

So the `class TagTrend_refine` should be in a separate file (usually called `models.py`) so that both your `dataloader.py`, and your `knowledge.py`, can `import models` to access it (and `models.py` will need its own import of `ndb` of course). (Then of course access to the entity class will be as `models.TagTrend_refine` -- very basic Python).

Next, you'll complete `dataloader.py` by defining a WSGI app, e.g, at end of file,

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(routes=[('/migratedata', MigrateData)])
```

(of course this means this module will need to import `webapp2` as well -- can I take for granted a knowledge of super-elementary Python?).

In `app.yaml`, as the **first** URL, **before** that `/.*`, you'll have:

```
url: /migratedata
script: dataloader.app
```

Given all this, when you visit '/migratedata', your handler will read the `"tagTrend_refine.txt"` file that you uploaded together with your `.py`, `.yaml`, and so on, files in your overall GAE application, and unconditionally create one entity per line of that file (assuming you fix the multiple indentation problems in your code as displayed above, but, again, this is just super-elementary Python -- presumably you've used both tabs and spaces and they show up OK in your editor, but not here on SO... I recommend you use strictly, only spaces, never tabs, in Python code).

However this does seem to be a peculiar task. If /migratedata gets visited twice, it will create duplicates of all entities. If you change the tagTrend_refine.txt and deploy a changed variation, then visit /migratedata... all old entities will stick around and all the new entities will join them. And so forth.

Moreover -- /migratedata is NOT idempotent (if visited more than once it does not produce the same state as running it just once) so it *shouldn't* be a GET (and now we're on to super-elementary HTTP for a change!-) -- it should be a POST.

In fact I suspect (but I'm really flying blind here, since you see fit to give such tiny amounts of information) that you in fact want to upload a .txt file to a POST handler and do the updates that way (perhaps avoiding duplicates...?). However, I'm no mind reader, so this is about as far as I can go.

I believe I have fully answered the question you *posted* (though perhaps not the one you *meant* but didn't **express**:-) and by SO's etiquette it would be nice to upvote and accept this answer, then, if needed, post *another* question, expressing *MUCH* more clearly and completely what you're trying to achieve, your current .py and .yaml (ideally with correct indentation), what they actually do and why you'd like to do something different. For POST vs GET in particular, just study [When should I use GET or POST method? What's the difference between them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504947/when-should-i-use-get-or-post-method-whats-the-difference-between-them) ...

Answer (score 0):

Alex's solution will work, as long as all you data can be loaded in under 1 minute, as that's the timeout for an app engine request.

For larger data, consider calling the datastore API directly from your own computer where you have the source.  It's a bit of a hassle because it's a different API; it's not ndb.  But it's still a pretty simple API.  Here's some code that calls the API:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-python/blob/master/2-structured-data/bookshelf/model_datastore.py

Again, this code can run anywhere.  It doesn't need to be uploaded to app engine to run.