# php $_POST variable is not saving

Tags: php, post

I currently have some php code on a form action, and it is being updated to the form's next page with

```html
<?php echo $_POST['var here']; ?>
```

and it is working, but I noticed when Im trying to refresh the page it asks to confirm resubmission. When I resubmit it works in that tab in which it was sumbitted, but in another new tab it does not show the displayed php post variables. I even took it the next step by seeing that when I open the 2nd page after the form action has been submitted the php post variables are gone...

Help!

Thanks!

Comment: May you please reword what your trying to say? Its confusing...

Comment: sure, Basically im trying to use form action to of course redirect to a new page. On that new page I used the post variables from the form to add to the new page. Right now when I refresh and confirm re-submission or open the same page in a new browser it does not load the php echo $_POST var's this removes all content from my page. And it seems as if the php post variables were almost being stored like cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submit a form with `<form method="post" />` it does a *post request* to the server, thus populating `$_POST`. When you open the link in a new tab it is no longer a post request but a *get request*. That is why you'll see nothing in `$_POST`.

`$_POST` — usually from forms
`$_GET` - from values on the URL (the query string `myscript.php?myvar=Joe`)

You can find plenty of resource about it. [You can start here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504947/when-should-i-use-get-or-post-method-whats-the-difference-between-them)

If you want to keep the values you can save them to the session:

```
<?php 
session_start(); // should be at the top of your php

if (isset($_POST['var'])) {
   $_SESSION['var'] = $_POST['var'];
}

$myvar = isset($_SESSION['var']) ? $_SESSION['var'] : "no var";

echo $myvar;
```

Now the value is stored in the session so you can visit the page in a new tab and it will still be there.

Comment: thanks so much, so to keep displaying the vars I would have to change them to get instead of post?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like desired behavior. The `$_POST` variable should only be filled when the post action is created. If you're looking to store variables across pages you could store it in either the `$_SESSION` var in PHP or deal with the front end `$_COOKIE` business. If you're always going to be rendering pages from the backend then `$_SESSION` is the way to go. It's never too late to read up on [cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php) and [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php).

The skinny of it is that you're going to want to do something like this:

```
<?php 
session_start();
if ($_POST['var']) {
  $_SESSION['var'] = $_POST['var'];
}

echo $_SESSION['var'] ?: $defaultValue;
```

Then you'll notice that the message changes only when you post and won't exist before then.