# Should I use GET or POST to send commands to server?

Tags: python, post, get, server

I am developing a simple application in python that provides a browser based interface using a local server. The structure is like this:

```
[Interface] <===> {  [Server] <---> [Application]  }
```

My application has a class function called, say, `compute()`. On my browser interface, I have a button *Compute*. When the user clicks it, I want to run `compute()`. My current approach is to send a `GET` request like `/path/compute`. The server identifies the request path and runs the function. Is this the correct way to go about it?

From [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504947/when-should-i-use-get-or-post-method-whats-the-difference-between-them):

> GET is used for viewing something, without changing it, while POST is used for changing something

I am not using `GET` here to view something immediately, but to send a command that changes the state of the application. Should I use `POST` instead? Is there another method?

Comment: If it changes state of the application then `POST` request is preferred

Comment: doesn't matter if a local app.  But use `POST` for centralized all request.

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed, you must use a POST request here. You may want to read about REST APIs for more about the correct use of http verbs. The HTTP rfc is also a must-read...