# how to ignore input from the user entered through the URL using php

Tags: php

I would like others to explain how to ignore any input from the user that is provided through the URL?

For example; if i have a URL like `viewitem.php?id=23` and if the user replaces the id with `34` i want to redirect them to an error page even if that `id` is available, can anyone show me how to do that?

Comment: Do you submit a Form?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `GET` variables, `GET` variables are easy to manipulate via the URL.

Use `POST` instead.

This isn't a sure fire way to prevent it, but it makes it much harder to modify the request from a browser when using `POST`

---

See also:
[When should I use GET or POST method? What's the difference between them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504947/when-should-i-use-get-or-post-method-whats-the-difference-between-them)

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1:** URL like `viewitem.php?id=23`

Make use of `POST` method while submitting form. `GET` method exposes data as well as it has limititation on no of characters can be send after submit.

**Question 2:** i want to redirect them to an error page even if that id is available, can anyone show me how to do that?

For this check internally if the ID is available in your database if not use.

```
header('Location: redirect-page.php');
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php