# Passing data from one page to another using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have 2 pages called `testing.php` and `submission.php`. What I am looking to achieve is sending data from `testing.php` to display that data in `submission.php`. For example, if a user clicks on `test1` they will get directed to `submission.php` and I would like to display `test1` on that page. Here is my code:

testing.php:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <ul id="choose">
            <li class="nav"><a href="submission.php">test1</a></li>
            <li class="nav"><a href="submission.php">test2</a></li>
            <li class="nav"><a href="submission.php">test3</a></li>
            <li class="nav"><a href="submission.php">test4</a></li>
            <li class="nav"><a href="submission.php">test5</a></li>
            <li class="nav"><a href="submission.php">test6</a></li> 
        </ul>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {    
            $("#choose").on('click', '.nav', function() {
                $.post("submission.php", { data: $(this).text() }, alert($(this).text()));               
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

submission.php:

```
<?php
    $subcat = $_POST['data'];
    echo $subcat;
?>
```

At the moment submission.php is showing below error;

> Notice: Undefined index: data in C:\xampp\htdocs\series\dynamics\admin\CleanURL\submission.php on line 2

Thanks in advance for looking into it, please suggest how could I get around this problem!

Comment: If you actually want to redirect the user to `submission.php` to show the data then you don't need AJAX, just use a standard `form` element

Answer (score 0):

This is what is happening:

1. You click the link
2. The event fires
3. The JavaScript runs
4. The Ajax request is prepped
5. The link is followed
6. The Ajax request is aborted because the page it lives it no longer exists

`$_POST` is empty because you are making a regular GET request by following a link.

First, [be unobtrusive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Replace the link with a form (alternatively design the system to use `GET` requests, it depends on [what the system is doing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504947/when-should-i-use-get-or-post-method-whats-the-difference-between-them)). Put a hidden input in it to set the value of `data`.

Then, to make it Ajaxy:

1. Bind the event handler to the forms submit event
2. Capture the event object
3. Prevent the default behaviour

You also need to pass a *function* as the third argument to `$.post`.

Such:

```
$("#choose").on('submit','form', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $.post(
      "submission.php",
      {data: this.form.data.value}, 
      function (response) { alert(response); }            
   );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest to achieve this is using GET and requires no javascript.

```
<ul id="choose">
    <li class="nav"><a href="submission.php?data=test1">test1</a></li>
    <li class="nav"><a href="submission.php?data=test2">test2</a></li>
    <li class="nav"><a href="submission.php?data=test3">test3</a></li>
    <li class="nav"><a href="submission.php?data=test4">test4</a></li>
    <li class="nav"><a href="submission.php?data=test5">test5</a></li>
    <li class="nav"><a href="submission.php?data=test6">test6</a></li> 
</ul>
```

Your submission.php.

```
<?php
$subcat = $_GET['data'];
echo $subcat;
?>
```

However if you really want/need to use POST then it's a bit more code and requires javascript.
First wrap your ul in form and add radio inputs to each item and hide them:

```
<form action="submission.php" method="post">
    <ul id="choose">
        <li class="nav"><input type="radio" name="data" value="test1" style="display: none" /><a href="#">test1</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><input type="radio" name="data" value="test2" style="display: none" /><a href="#">test2</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><input type="radio" name="data" value="test3" style="display: none" /><a href="#">test3</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><input type="radio" name="data" value="test4" style="display: none" /><a href="#">test4</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><input type="radio" name="data" value="test5" style="display: none" /><a href="#">test5</a></li>
        <li class="nav"><input type="radio" name="data" value="test6" style="display: none" /><a href="#">test6</a></li> 
    </ul>
</form>
```

When you click on a link, use javascript to make the proper radio input checked and submit the form.

```
$("#choose").on('click', '.nav', function() {
    $(this).find('input').prop('checked', true);
    $('form').submit();               
});
```

Then you can use your submission.php code.

```
<?php
$subcat = $_POST['data'];
echo $subcat;
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

**With Form**

```
<form action="submission.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

**With AJAX**

```
   var data = (this).text();
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "submission.php",
      data: { li_selected: data}
    })
      .done(function( msg ) {
        alert( "Response: " + msg );
      });
```

I think that you want to use ajax ones.