# Differentiate between multiple buttons on a table. html php

Tags: php, html

I am creating an edit edit/delete user table and have created an 'edit' button for each record populated in the table. I want to do several things. 
1. when an edit button is pressed for a specific user, open a new page called "EDIT."
2. populate form controls in the "EDIT" page with the corresponding user information for the specific 'edit' button that was pressed.

My question is, how do I differentiate between which button is pressed on the users table?

this is what my table looks like:

[image]

And this is the code for generating the table and buttons.

```js
if (!$_REQUEST['search']) {

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users_table ORDER BY lname ASC";

  $retvalues = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

  $counter = 1;

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($retvalues, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    $lname = capword($row['lname']);
    $fname = capword($row['fname']);

    if ($row['admin'] != 1) {
      $stringAdmin = "No";
      $admincolor = "<td>";

    } else {
      $stringAdmin = "Yes";
      $admincolor = "<td style='color:red;'>";
    }
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$counter.".</td>";
    echo "<td>".$lname." , ".$fname."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['email']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['password']."</td>";
    echo $admincolor.$stringAdmin."</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='user[]' value='{$row['id']}'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='submit' name='edit' value='edit'></td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    $counter++;
  }
}
```

Comment: I would give each edit button an numbered ID which corresponds to the row number (e.g. id="edit-button-2" for the button from second row)

Comment: Your approach seems off to me. Inputs are meant to be on form inside form tag. If you want to differentiate buttons though, you can use unique id's, and process data afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

You can differentiate the each edit button by using unique id

```
<button class='edit' data-id="<?php echo $_GET["id"];?>"> EDIT</button>.
```

While click on the edit button, read the data-id by using the following code

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
 //code - you need to do
})
```

Better to show the data on next page, use bootstrap model box and AJAX request which will interact lot of the users.

```
 $(document).on('click', '.edit', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    if(id) {
        $.ajax({
            url : your url("profile/edit/"+id)
            type : 'post',
            success: function(response){
                if (response.success) {
                    $('#modal').modal('show');
                }
            }
        }):
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the value attribute of "Edit" submit button to the row id you can use this value to know what record id will be edited and populate it.

```
"<input type='submit' name='edit' value='edit'>"
```

change to

```
"<button name='edit' value='{$row['id']}'>Edit</button>"
```

Note that if the whole table is the form container, all inputs in table will be posted, not only the current row.

Answer (score 0):

I would make the edit button into a hyperlink instead. Then there's no need to  have form code. I'm assuming you don't need to pass the "delete" parameter to your edit page (as that's a different operation).

Instead of

```
echo "<td><input type='submit' name='edit' value='edit'></td>";
```

write

```
echo "<td><a href='edit.php?id=".$row['id']."'>Edit</a></td>";
```

Then in edit.php look for the variable

```
$_GET["id"]
```

and use that to search the database and display the appropriate record for editing.

P.S. If you still want your "Edit" hyperlink to look like a button it's quite easy to do that with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I did this by creating and calling a javaScript function that passes the id of the row as an argument.

```
echo"<tr>";
                                    echo"<td>".$counter. ".</td>";
                                    echo"<td>".$lname. " , " .$fname."</td>";
                                    echo"<td>".$row['email']."</td>";
                                    echo"<td>".$row['password']."</td>";
                                    echo $admincolor . $stringAdmin ."</td>";
                                    echo"<td><input type='checkbox' name='user[]' value='{$row['id']}'></td>";
                                    echo"<td><input type='button' name='edit' value='edit' onclick='javascript:editUser(". $row['id'].");'></td>";
                                echo"</tr>";
```

the function redirects the user to an 'edit' page while passing the value of the id in the url.

```
function editUser(id){

                window.location = "edituser.php?id="+id;

            }
```

once on the edit page, i used $_GET to retrieve the id value and edit my entry.

Answer (score -1):

You can change and add a form to your table like this:

```
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".$counter.".</td>";
echo "<td>".$lname." , ".$fname."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['email']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['password']."</td>";
echo $admincolor.$stringAdmin."</td>";
<form action="edit.php" method="post">
  echo "<input type="text" name="id" value="$row['id']" style="visibilty: hidden;">";
  echo "<td><input type="checkbox" name="delete"></td>";
  echo "<td><input type="submit" name="edit" value="edit"></td>";
</form>
echo "</tr>"
```

First we have defined a form with POST method: `<form action="edit.php" method="post">` and let's say **edit.php** will handle the request.

Then we have added a hidden form element to store and pass the user's ID: `<input type="text" name="id" value="$row['id']" style="visibilty: hidden;">` It was possible to use `value="..."` of "edit" button but if you are dealing with passing more than one variables with POST or GET method, the trick is using an extra form element with `visibility: hidden;` CSS property.

Eventually, it will pass the value of `$row['id']` to **edit.php** when the form has been submitted.

and we can handle the request in **edit.php** like this:

```
<html>
  <body>

    User with this ID number: <?php echo $_POST["id"]; ?> will be edited.

  </body>
</html>
```

Official guide: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

You can either use POST or GET method to pass the variables. For a detailed comparison: https://stackoverflow.com/a/504993/2104879