# What is the best method to pass ID with Ajax call?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

I'm New in AJAX.

When passing ID to update product. Any explanation for this. Thank you in advance.

This

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'post',
   url: 'my_controller/update_product_exe/' + id, //This line
   dataType: 'json'
});
```

to this...

```
$.ajax({
   type:'post',
   url: 'my_controller/update_product_exe',
   dataType: 'json',
   data: {id: id} // this line
});
```

Comment: **in second** you will get the data in $_POST, **in first**, you will get the id in segment of CI

Comment: data: {id: id} it means you want to pass data to API

Comment: Ahh. Which better to use, the first one to the second one???

Comment: It depends if your API expects parameters to be passed in the URL or in the POST body. There is no "better" one, although I would say the first one is more explanatory at first glance.

Comment: I disagree.. there is one that is better. See my answer

Answer (score 4):

The difference is the `url` itself. Appending `id` to the first `url` will change it and therefore send the request to that specific `url`. But, it's not sending any data during request. Example:

```
// let's say id = "1234"
$.ajax({
   type: 'post',
   url: 'my_controller/update_product_exe/' + id, // This will be 'my_controller/update_product_exe/1234'
   dataType: 'json'
});
```

And for the second one:

```
$.ajax({
   type:'post',
   url: 'my_controller/update_product_exe',
   dataType: 'json',
   data: {id: id} // This will be {id: "1234"}
});
```

On the second one, you are passing data; on the first one, you are just modifying your `url` by appending some string to it.

Comment: Which is the best AJAX SYNTAX?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to know about the difference in both ajax requests than:

**In first request**, you are not passing the data in ajax request but sending an ID in URL, in CI controller, you will get this id by using URL Segments.

**In Second request**, you are sending the data in ajax request, so you can get the data in controller by using `$_POST`

Now, which one is the better, both of them having difference, when you need to pass some input values using ajax than you can choose second one. You can send multiple data in this request.

You can also use second request for achieving the first request target, in this case you can just pass the ID in ajax data. You can send multiple data but you must need to take of segement URLs.

Comment: I would like to ask, which is better?

Comment: @Marky: best in the sense of?? what?

Comment: I was wondering which of that two I would use to update product, because both of them are running properly :(

Comment: @devpro Isn't the first one modifying the URL? Making it, for example, 'my_controller/update_product_exe/someid' ? Therefore shouldn't it request to another URL? (Unless the server handles it first)

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually you are using a GET in the the first example and a POST for the second. HTTP [verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) have a meaning and POST is meant to send information to a server. Even if you can get the id by using a GET this does not make it semantically correct. For the moment you only have an id which is limited in size and is only one parameter, but even in a small application one usually sends to a server several parameters and maybe some kb of data. GET parameters are limited in size and POST is better suited for this.

**For all this reasons the second version that is using POST is the correct one.**

Here are some extra resources on the differences between GET and POST.

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/the-definitive-guide-to-get-vs-post

http://www.diffen.com/difference/GET-vs-POST-HTTP-Requests

[What is the difference between POST and GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get)

[When should I use GET or POST method? What's the difference between them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504947/when-should-i-use-get-or-post-method-whats-the-difference-between-them)