# No values in POST method's parameters

Tags: c#, rest

I have `REST` web services `POST` method:

```
public string Post([FromBody]string value1 )  
{
    return "a";
}
```

I have placed breakpoint inside of it. I have sent POST:

```
localhost/RESTServer/api/Person/?value1=1
```

I get `null` in `value1` inside of `Post` method. What I do wrong?

Comment: You are making a GET request to a POST method?

Comment: You should prob read [When should I use GET or POST method? What's the difference between them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504947/when-should-i-use-get-or-post-method-whats-the-difference-between-them)

Comment: I use POST method

Answer (score 5):

```
public string Post([FromBody]string value1 )
```

should be

```
public string Post([QueryString]string value1 )
```

(that is ... because your request is a GET and has no body... pure guess)

Comment: Well, the request *could* be a `POST`, the question didn't specify.  But regardless of the request type, the value is still in the query string.

Comment: sure... but when i read the question, something tells me that it is very likely a GET ;) ... but you are right... it might be a POST

Comment: I'm trying to use POST. But 'FromBody' was generated by Visual Studio 2015 and if I place 'QueryString' I get error 'The type or namespace name 'QueryStringAttribute' could not be found'

Comment: a new using directive might help you... `using System.Web.ModelBinding;`

Comment: This helped with QueryString. But now I have '405 Method Not Allowed' in client side.

Comment: different problem -> different question

Answer (score 0):

I see you are just learning WebApi I recommend you this page: http://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.mx/2016/09/aspnet-web-api-tutorial-for-beginners.html by far the best tutorial out there.

Also about your problem : [image]

Your post request should look something like this, if you intend to use Post