# Rest , send parameter with Get as query string or just use Post to get information

Tags: java, rest, architecture

i need to expose Rest API which retrieve information about `Brand` based on `brandId`,
so i need to send `brandId` parameter. 
from Rest Architecture and Design perspective, should i use `Post` (with the parameter in the body), or use `Get` and send the parameter as query string or header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used GET, and sent the parameter `brandId` as path variable

Answer (score 1):

You should use GET. POST is used to put or update some new information into service/database.

Try to read this: [What is the difference between POST and GET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get)

And this: [When should I use GET or POST method? What's the difference between them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504947/when-should-i-use-get-or-post-method-whats-the-difference-between-them?noredirect=1&lq=1)