# AJAX Post request not sending values to Django View

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I am trying to pass some data from the frontend to the backend of my site using AJAX. This is the post request view in my django views:

```
def post(self, request):
    id_ = request.GET.get('teacherID', None)
    print(id_)
    args = {}   
    return JsonResponse(args)
```

This is the function I have in javascript. I know the correct value is being passed because the `console.log(teacher_id)` prints the right value.

```
function send(teacher_id){
    console.log(teacher_id)
    var url = window.location.pathname;
      $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: {
            'teacherID': teacher_id,
            },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            //location.href = data.url;//<--Redirect on success
        }
        });
}
```

When the code is run, and the print statement in my view is run, regardless of what the teacher_id is, `None` is printed.

what is wrong with the code?

Comment: can you add contentType in your Ajax request - `contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",` , and try once.

Comment: You are retrieving the data using ```GET.get()``` while sending the request using ```method: "POST"```. My knowledge of Django isn't existent but language wise there's a mismatch there so I thought that might be it. Let me know if that's the issue so I can post an answer.

Comment: @yarwest you were right, thanks for the help! Post the answer and Ill accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Django view the data is being retrieved using `GET.get()` while the AJAX request is sending it using `method: "POST"`.

`POST` data can't be retrieved in the same way as `GET` data so you should either change the way the data is being send (by changing the `method` in the AJAX call to `GET`) or read it using the related `POST` methods.

You can visit [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504947/when-should-i-use-get-or-post-method-whats-the-difference-between-them) if you are doubting which method to use.