# isset_POST in PHP always false

Tags: php, post, connection

Hello developers out there,

I want a php file communicate between android application and mysql server. Because I had alot of trouble setting this up, I tried to learn it step by step because none of the tutorials I found so far is working for me. After a while I understod that my php file does not get any _POST response.

This is the php file:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    echo $_POST['id'];
}else{
    echo "no id";
}
if(isset($_POST['stringdata'])){
    echo $_POST['stringdata'];
}else{
    echo "no stringdata";
}
?>
```

which always shows "no idno stringdata" (tested with postman and other files also tested with android studio). So in every file this "isset($_POST['stringdata']))" gives false.

Now my question: what am I doing wrong? How can I give variables to the php file?
Thank you :)

EDIT:

How I said I am doing it with "Postman", this programm gives this line to submit it if I am getting it right:

localhost/android_connect/testscript.php?id=123&stringdata=whatever

Comment: Show us the code you are using to submit this. You probably aren't posting anything with the name being `stringdata`

Comment: Try `print_r($_POST)` and show us what you have.

Comment: Also make sure you are submitting a post request not a get...

Comment: Post variables are submitted through a form

Comment: @BobbyAxe that is not 100% accurate. You can submit a post in many ways as well as a get.

Comment: @BobbyAxe there is no way to populate `$_POST` variable with a GET request but if you set your form like `method= "GET"` it is a get. If you curl data using POST it is post. The OP said he is using Postman which lets you choose your method  `GET, POST, PUT, PATCH...` the list is long. Point is it being a form is irreverent.

Comment: print_r($_POST) gives me: Array (), and I am making it with POST

Comment: @nerdlyist please read the question again to understand my comment. Yes a form is not the only way, but consider this line `I want a php file communicate between android application and mysql server`

Comment: And to understand it more clear: I just wrote the introduction to get my overall goal, but for now i just want the make sure that my php script it getting this POST right

Comment: @BobbyAxe this would help my point that a form is irreverent this should be an API call on POST.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I use GET or POST method? What's the difference between them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504947/when-should-i-use-get-or-post-method-whats-the-difference-between-them)

Comment: @nerdlyist i believed that op was using postman for testing purposes not as part of main project but if that not be the case then your answer should be perfect for op's question

Comment: @BobbyAxe and nerdlyist: Maybe you guys could answer my new problem posted some minutes ago, I would be so glad: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52843267/insert-data-into-mysql-db-with-php-script-doesnt-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to submit a `POST` request in Postman

The uri `localhost/android_connect/testscript.php?id=123&stringdata=whatever` is submitting query paramas which are for a `GET` request.

There are couple solutions:

Use `$_GET`:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    echo $_GET['id'];
}else{
    echo "no id";
}
//... other code
?>
```

Be lazy with `$_REQUEST`this one check both `$_POST` and `$_GET` but I would not recommend it.

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])){
    echo $_REQUEST['id'];
}else{
    echo "no id";
}
//... other code
?>
```

Update you call to be a `POST`and then set the data to send and leave your code as is.

[image: Change Method]

Comment: thanks a lot, this actually helped me a lot more than you probably think :)

Comment: @Pumpanickel you would be surprised we've all been there sometimes a little extra help goes a long ways

Comment: yes, i am alot in android development and now want to have a connection to mysql server but having huge problems with that... but it'll work some day... :D

Comment: @nerdlyist seems your right :) its part of the main project, an API i think? +1