# Insert data into mysql db with php script doesnt work

Tags: php, android, android-volley

Hello developers out there,

I am trying to insert data from my Android Application into my MySql Server (running on wamp) with php script.

Thhose are my php scripts:

```
<?php

define('hostname','localhost');
define('user','root');
define('password','');
define('databaseName','tutorial');

$connect = mysqli_connect(hostname,user,password,databaseName);

?>
```

AND

```
<?php

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST") {

    require 'connection.php';
    createStudent();

}

function createstudent(){

    global $connect;

    $firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
    $lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
    $age = $_POST["age"];

    $query = "insert into student(firstname,lastname,age) values ('$firstname','$lastname','$age');";

    mysqli_query($connect,$query) or die (mysqli_error($connect));
    mysqli_close($connect);

}

?>
```

and this is my android code:

```
requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

                StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, insertUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                }){
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String,String> parameters = new HashMap<String,String>();
                        parameters.put("firstname",et_firstname.getText().toString());
                        parameters.put("lastname",et_lastname.getText().toString());
                        parameters.put("age",et_age.getText().toString());

                        return parameters;

                    }
                };

                requestQueue.add(request);
```

Let me say: I know this is quiet a complex question but I am pretty much at the end of my ideas, searching for the solution since weeks and I would be so glad if someone could help me, also because I am not very much into php I can't help myself too much.

Thank you
greetings
Alex

EDIT

When I run the script on Postman filling the data, those errors appear:

[Postman error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKHkA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I finally got what the problem was, if somebody else has this problem:

I was running another MySql Server I installed some time ago and forgot about it. So this one was running on my default port. I deinstalled this server and changed the port of my "real" server to the default port.

Anyways big thanks to everybody who tried to help me, which helped me get to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the connection.

The correct syntax is

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
```

So, it must be

```
$connect = mysqli_connect(hostname,user,password,databaseName);
```

**remove the empty parenthesis**

Comment: oh yes this was a tiping mistake, put its still not working

Answer (score 0):

Can you access PhpMyAdmin using a browser? The error points out that the database was not accessible using your PHP application.

If you can't, make sure it is properly installed and is working.

If you can, make sure mysqli driver is installed. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285141/is-mysqli-extension-enabled-in-this-php-configuration) to see if you have mysqli driver was installed and configured.

Comment: Yes i can access PhpMyAdmin in my browser. And also the function:var_dump(function_exists('mysqli_connect')); prints true

Comment: What is the URL of your PHPmyAdmin?

is it like `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` or you are using like `http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin`?

if so use the port number you are using like:
`
$port = 8080; 

$connect = mysqli_connect(hostname.':'.$port,user,password,databaseName);`

Answer (score 0):

Check your api first by running it on some online website and check if your db name is correct by simply inserting some data through a php script running on web and if problem not solve it might be problem in your connection of db.

Comment: yes i think it's a problem with the db connection. I changed the port where mySql is running, maybe it has something to do with this?

Comment: it might be the case and also check your internet connection may be your firewall is blocking the connection and if not check ip addresses.

Comment: what do you mean by checking the ip adresses? i tried doing it woth avira deactivated, doenst change a thing

Comment: By ip address i mean to say that your android app and php script both using same internet connection like 192.168.10.xx

Comment: i am just using localhost

Comment: Alright then it might be dB connection which is causing the problem.

Comment: a question, when i change the port of the mysql server, do i have to change something else?

Comment: did you check your computer's or laptop's firewall may be it is blocking connection between your android and web app.

Comment: i finally solved it (see solution) but big thank to you anyway :)