# Why someone calls post() method inside get() method in Servlets?

Tags: java, post, servlets, get, http-method

why we call `post()` method inside `get()` method in servlets?

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
      throws ServletException, IOException {

      doGet(request, response);
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply only because someone wants to have the same behavior disregarding the HTTP method whether it was `POST` or `GET`. So requesting resource with  `POST` does the same as `GET`.

**BUT**: doing this - doing the same action - is quite propably wrong. Someone who does this might do it for convenience - for example wants to provide more means to access resource but does not fully understand the difference of `GET` vs. `POST`.

It is a matter of **idempotency**. Good explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/504947/6413377).

In a nutshell `GET` should be used when `GET`ting stuff and `POST`ing when you need to change stuff on the server side.

*But what I have experienced some people use `GET` as long as there too much data for `GET` and then switch to `POST` without further thinking about the real difference.*