# What can i do about GET requests when my route is POST?

Tags: laravel

I am currently working on a small web application to gain some experience. Everything is going pretty well and i am in the process of testing some features. The app has a page with an HTML form where someone can type a PIN number and that will query a database for an item. That item will then be displayed in another page.(let's call that the "display page")

Now obviously i am using a POST route to use the PIN input and get the item.

Today as i was doing some tests a friend came over and tried to access the "display page" by just typing the url in the browser(/items/display). All i got was an error from Laravel that literally said "No message".

I do get that he tried to make a GET request when my route is POST but i have no idea what to do in order to deal with this. It isn't that important but i see it as a learning opportunity.

Any insight is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Set `APP_DEBUG` in the `.env` to true and a detailed error message should be displayed.

Comment: Show your routes, Laravel shouldn't catch a GET request on a POST route, it should just pass down the request to the first route it matches. If it doesnt match any  routes, it should throw an exception.

Comment: `obviously i am using a POST` - why? [Convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504947/when-should-i-use-get-or-post-method-whats-the-difference-between-them) is to use `GET` to view something, and `POST` when *changing* something. You are simply retrieving data from a DB, which sounds like it should be `GET`.  That will incidentally solve your problem :-) As well as mean you can share URLs that go directly to query results, like `http://somewhere.com/display/123`, or `http://somewhere.com/display?pin=123`

Answer (score 0):

You can change yout route from `Route::post('myurl')` to `Route::any('myurl')`, so all HTTP verbs will route to your controller, including `GET`.

You can also change your route from post to get, `Route::get('myurl')`, and change your form to make a get request, adding the tag `method="GET"` to your form.