# Trying to pass value to ISSET condition but getting error

Tags: php

I have created a PHP script and if use the script its always going to else condition and I am not sure why its not going to else condition.

```
  <?php
   require_once  'db_functions.php';
   $db = new DB_Functions();
   $response = array();

   $phone="1234";
   $name="Test";
   $birthdate="1994-01-01";
   $address="123 M";

    if(isset($_POST['phone']) &&
    isset($_POST['name']) &&
    isset($_POST['birthdate']) &&
    isset($_POST['address']))


   {
    echo "Hello World 1";

    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $birthdate = $_POST['birthdate'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];

    echo "Hello World 2";

   }

   else{

    echo "Hello";
    $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameter 
    (phone,name,birthdate,address) is missing!";
    echo json_encode($response);
    }
    ?>
```

**Output:**

_msg":"Required parameter (phone,name,birthdate,address) is missing!"}

If the value is passed then it should go to if condition instead of else condition.

**Options Tried**

Tried Below options but I am getting empty value:

$test=$_POST['phone'];
echo "Hey......".$test;

echo isset($_POST['phone']);

**URL USED**
https://www.aaa.ccc/php/register.php?phone=232&name=test&birthdate=1954-04-04&address=232

Comment: To get a better idea try to print each of the conditions and also `$_POST`. like `echo isset($_POST['phone'])`

Comment: You are checking for $_POST in your if condition but the variable you have assigned are local. Are you sure you are getting anything in $_POST.

Comment: I am getting error unexpected T_ECHO.  if(echo isset($_POST['phone']) && 
    echo isset($_POST['name']) &&
    echo isset($_POST['birthdate']) &&
    echo isset($_POST['address']))

Comment: You don't need to echo inside a IF statement, the way you have described your code in question is fine.

Comment: Try using `$_GET[]` instead of `$_POST[]`

Comment: Are you posting data by submitting a `<form>` with `method="post"`? It might help to include the relevant HTML in your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I use GET or POST method? What's the difference between them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504947/when-should-i-use-get-or-post-method-whats-the-difference-between-them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the parameters in the url using the `GET` method, not `POST`, so you need:

```
 <?php
   require_once  'db_functions.php';
   $db = new DB_Functions();
   $response = array();

   $phone="1234";
   $name="Test";
   $birthdate="1994-01-01";
   $address="123 M";

    if(isset($_GET['phone']) &&
    isset($_GET['name']) &&
    isset($_GET['birthdate']) &&
    isset($_GET['address']))


   {
    echo "Hello World 1";

    $phone = $_GET['phone'];
    $name = $_GET['name'];
    $birthdate = $_GET['birthdate'];
    $address = $_GET['address'];

    echo "Hello World 2";

   }

   else{

    echo "Hello";
    $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameter 
    (phone,name,birthdate,address) is missing!";
    echo json_encode($response);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: GET is working fine but why Post is not working in this case.

Comment: ARC POST is working but its not working via web link