# How to push notification to Joomla plugin

Tags: joomla, notifications

I want to push some `POST` data to my plugin in `Joomla`.
But I don't know how to receive the data in my plugin.

Do I have to `POST` them to some kind of `URL` as
`index.php?option=task=pluginnotification&no_html=1` ?
Any help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I use GET or POST method? What's the difference between them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504947/when-should-i-use-get-or-post-method-whats-the-difference-between-them)

Comment: No, I don't ask about POST/GET but how to receive the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only components are supposed to handle URLs directly. There is exactly one component per page which is responsible for handling incoming data. So in general, you can't send data to a plugin.

But of course, there are workarounds. Given the fact that the component which is addressed by the POST target URL ignores your data, you can access that data in your plugin code. If you want to handle the data earlier, create an additional system plugin which runs before the rendering process.

The best solution is definitely creating a dedicated component which handles the incoming data and responds in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

first way : if you want , you can send data to AJAX plugins.
for this way read ajax component in joomla:
https://docs.joomla.org/Using_Joomla_Ajax_Interface

secend way : or you can create EVENT for your Component and call this event befor or after save data
in this case you access form data before or after save and you can manipulate data