# Using GET for sending information to server in REST APIs

Tags: rest, api, post, get, semantics

Until now, I used to think the only difference between GET and POST is the format on data trasmission.
In other examples I have seen that in REST Api, the only command to send information is POST, while for getting information is GET...

But what if I want to use GET also for information sending? I have to send a number of dataset names to be processed (usually a short number...)... I don't understand why GET doesn't fits this operation. Or it's only a "semantic" reason?

EDIT: I don't want answer about the general differences between GET or POST... I need to know if GET should not be used to update info of the server IN ALL CASES, in particular regarding my specific case, or there are some exceptions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I use GET or POST method? What's the difference between them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504947/when-should-i-use-get-or-post-method-whats-the-difference-between-them)

Comment: No, as I have edited...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand why GET doesn't fits this operation. Or it's only a "semantic" reason?

Yes, but semantics are the entire point.

One of the important constraints of the [REST architectural style](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) is that of a [uniform interface](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_5); the idea that all components understand messages the same way.  What that gives us is the ability to achieve useful work using general purpose components.

In HTTP (an application built within the constraints of this style), that means that we can use browsers, and caches, and reverse proxies, and server toolkits, and so forth, mixing and matching as we go.  It all works, because all of these components understand that a request should be interpreted as described in RFC 7230, and that the [request method token](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4) is "the primary source of request semantics", and so on.

The semantics of [GET](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.1) have been defined, and we all share in that definition.  The wording of the definition has evolved somewhat from its earliest specifications, but the basic semantics have been constant: that GET is effectively read-only, and that the message body (of the request) is of no semantic interest.

If you want to use an HTTP method where the message body is semantically significant, then you need to either relax some of the constraints of GET (for instance, by using POST), choose a different standardized method that better fits your use case (see the [IANA HTTP Method Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-methods/http-methods.xhtml)), or by defining (and potentially [standardizing](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-8.1.2)) your own HTTP method.

The core problem with trying to define a payload for GET - while your bespoke client may know what to do, and your bespoke resource may know what to do, general-purpose intermediates are likely to do the *wrong* thing (like caching responses without capturing the information in the request body, or discarding the body as unnecessary).

Note that information that is *encoded into the target-uri* works just fine; HTML forms using the GET method and other variations of URI templates can be used to construct a target-uri from local information that the server can interpret (of course, the defacto limits on target-uri length are much shorter than the defacto limits on payload size; it's not a universal solution).