# Why is this HTML form not submitting the parameters?

Tags: html, forms, parameters, submit

I have just a quick question. Does someone know why this html page (a form) does not work?

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form method=POST action=show-query-params>
<p>
<input type=text name=foo id=foo size=20 value=nameee />
</p>
<p>
<input name=submit type=submit value=submit />
<input type=reset value=Reset />
</p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click **submit**, the page "http://localhost:8080/show-query-params" is opened but with no parameters.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean? what do you want? Also, show the code of the action file mentioned in the form, please.

Comment: In your example, you need quotes around everything to the right of any `=` sign.

Comment: @RobMoll — No, they don't. It's HTML not XML.

Comment: @Quentin My bad. I think you meant to say XHTML - not XML.

Answer (score 0):

Data gets added to the query string of the URL when you submit a form with `method="GET"` (the default).

You have set `method="POST"` so the data be will placed in the request *body* and not visible in the URL.

You can inspect it using the Network tab in your browser's Developer Tools.

See also: [When should I use GET or POST method? What's the difference between them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504947/when-should-i-use-get-or-post-method-whats-the-difference-between-them).

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the difference between GET and POST parameters. A GET parameter appears after the URL in your browser window, as you expected. A POST parameter will not appear after the URL.

You can change your method to GET at your `form` tag to reach the behavior you desire.