# PHP How to get dynamic header data?

Tags: php, swift

I am creating an app for the company I work for. I need to pass data from the app (SWIFT) to PHP. The problem is the data I am passing is dynamic and can change. Heres an example

http://www.website.com/inventory.php?variable=data&variable=data

There are going to be different variables (up to 300). The names of the variables will change

How do I get all variables passes in php without necessarily knowing the names of them?

Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would suggest passing dynamic data items in an array via POST, not GET ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504947)), however if you want to get all the variables from the URL string, simply access the `$_GET` superglobal.

For example, the following code will output all the URL parameters:

```
print_r($_GET);
```

Input: `file.php?item1=77&item2=99` would output

```
Array
(
    [item1] => 77
    [item2] => 99
)
```

If you want to get the data from this, then it would be easiest to loop over them in a `foreach` loop, like so:

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
    echo "Key: $key";
    echo "Value: $value";
}
```