# What is the advantage of using a GET http method to update values as opposed to POST http method?

Tags: post, get, webhooks

I was [reading up on how to create a telegram bot](https://xabaras.medium.com/setting-your-telegram-bot-webhook-the-easy-way-c7577b2d6f72) and I see that to set a web hook you use the GET http method. I assume that your link will be stored somewhere on telegram servers.

So now my question is:
Why not use the POST http method? What is the advantage of this design of using GET http method in this case rather than POST http method for something that pushes data?

Comment: Bot API supports both GET *and* POST HTTP methods. It is up to you what to use.

Comment: I understand. But why include get http method though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bot API supports GET *and* POST HTTP methods both. It's up to you what to use. (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504947/when-should-i-use-get-or-post-method-whats-the-difference-between-them)). I think it makes the API easy and fast to get started with.

For the sake of simplicity one might choose a simple GET request to set a webhook - Put together a Url with some parameters and call it in a web browser, done! Webhook is now set.

Still it is possible to do the same with a POST request (and you can argue it is the preferred way to do so). But it would need tools like Postman, CURL  or some browser extensions.

Comment: Why does POST request need tools like Postman or Curl but the get method doesn't?