# Which API Method to use for sending Whatsapp Link?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, rest

I have to design a REST API which accepts few query parameters, fetches a template from database and then sends the whatsapp message to a particular user.

My question is which API method is most suitable and should be used for sending notifications to users?

Should it be `GET` method, `POST` method or any other method?

In response, it just sends a `success` message or `error` message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When should I use GET or POST method? What's the difference between them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504947/when-should-i-use-get-or-post-method-whats-the-difference-between-them)

Comment: No, I have searched everywhere and haven't got any answer as to which method should be used since neither am I retrieving data and sending it in response nor am I updating something in database.

Comment: Is the question what request method _your_ API endpoint should use - or is this about the WhatsApp API?

Comment: Yes, the question is what request method API endpoint should use?