# How to use Ajax for nested form on active admin rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-7, ajax-on-rails

**Please help me out with this problem. I am new on rails**

- I am trying to use the ajax method to get values on the active admin nested form. But only the top of the form gets dynamic values. After changing values on the top one form on the nested form then ajax makes a request then it changes the values(i.e. update the form values).
  But after adding a new buy line item then ajax makes a request but doesn't update the values on the form i.e.same values for every new buy line item.

**my js code**
**app/assets/javascripts/buys.js**

```
    // for nested buyline items of buys resources
    $('.lineItem').change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/admin/get_buys_buy_line_item',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                product_id: $('.lineBuyProduct').val(),
                buy_quantity: $(".lineBuyQuantity").val(),
                buy_quantity_unit: $(".lineBuyUnit").val(),
                buy_price: $(".lineBuyAmount").val(),
            },
            success: (data) => {
                alert(data);
                // if (data == null) {
                //     document.getElementById('lineQuantity').value = ' ';
                //     document.getElementById('lineAmount').value = ' ';
                // }
                // else {
                // document.getElementsByClassName("linebuyQuantity").value = data['1'];
                // document.getElementsByClassName('linebuyAmount').value = data[0];
                // console.log("Dynamic select OK!")
                // }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**My active admin forms**

```
f.inputs 'Line Items', class: "lineItem" do
      table do
        thead do
          tr do
            th 'S.N', class: 'form-table__col'
            th 'Product', class: 'form-table__col'
            th 'Quantity', class: 'form-table__col'
            th 'Unit', class: 'form-table__col'
            th 'Amount', class: 'form-table__col'
            th 'Expiry Date', class: 'form-table__col'
            th 'Destroy', class: 'form-table__col'
          end
        end
      end
      f.has_many :buy_line_items, new_record: 'Add Buy Line Item', heading: false, allow_destroy: true do |x|
        x.input :sn, label: false
        x.input :product, label: false, as: :select2, collection: Product.drop_down_options,
                          input_html: { required: true, class: 'lineBuyProduct' }
        x.input :buy_quantity, label: false, input_html: { required: true, class: 'lineBuyQuantity' }
        x.input :buy_quantity_unit, label: false, collection: Unit.all.pluck(:name),
                                    input_html: { class: 'lineBuyUnit' }
        x.input :buy_price, label: false,
                            input_html: { required: true, class: 'lineBuyAmount' }
        x.input :expiry_date, as: :date_picker, input_html: { style: 'width:auto' }, label: false
      end
    end
```

**Some of my screenshots of how my program behaves and what my expectations are**

- [In this image my first selection of product on buy line iteme then on request we can see json are renderd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlyFz.png)
- [But in this image after selecting another product again same json data are rendered that means doesn't update with different respective product values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctye5.png)
- [And there are also some problems on active admin blaze theme, after adding class on form then it changes to legend color and add item button colors to light brown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7QBW.png)
- [This picture is about after removing custom class name **lineItem**.But, after removing this class then ajax doesn't hit for that form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVMvf.png)
- Might be i faced such problem due to nested form's **class** on active admin.While i used default class of those form from inspect then it even doesn't hit to that form for ajax request.

So, please expert team help me to slove this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send the data to create a new entity(record), you need to use the http POST method: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/
The GET request it just retrieves an already existing entity. Probably that's why you can read some data after an ajax call, but it's not updated.

More about the differences between GET and POST methods:
[When should I use GET or POST method? What's the difference between them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504947/when-should-i-use-get-or-post-method-whats-the-difference-between-them)

If this fix doesn't work, check the rails logs.

Comment: No, this solution doesn't useful for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have never used anything related to Ruby, and I'm not completely sure if I understood your question. I'm assuming you have problems with the AJAX behavior for new items in the list. Considering that, I think your problem could be related to attaching the "change" event to the new items. I think there might be many different other ways to get the behavior you want, but I will just elaborate on your solution using JS.

From the [activeAdmin's code](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/b31318b8d05f2d7ab1c2a4d7078f8e1d47062517/app/javascript/active_admin/initializers/has-many.js#L37) you can see they trigger an event called "has_many_add:after" when a new item was successfully added to its parent. Considering that, I would try changing your Javascript code to:

```
// for nested buyline items of buys resources
$("#buy_line_items").on("has_many_add:after", function(event, fieldset, parent){
    fieldset.change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/admin/get_buys_buy_line_item',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                product_id: $(this).find('.lineBuyProduct').val(),
                buy_quantity: $(this).find(".lineBuyQuantity").val(),
                buy_quantity_unit: $(this).find(".lineBuyUnit").val(),
                buy_price: $(this).find(".lineBuyAmount").val()
             },
             success: (data) => {
                 alert(data);
                 // if (data == null) {
                 //     document.getElementById('lineQuantity').value = ' ';
                 //     document.getElementById('lineAmount').value = ' ';
                 // }
                 // else {
                 // document.getElementsByClassName("linebuyQuantity").value = data['1'];
                 // document.getElementsByClassName('linebuyAmount').value = data[0];
                 // console.log("Dynamic select OK!")
                 // }
             }
         });
    });
});
```

I'm very confident that this will work, mainly because I don't have how to try it (if you give me the generated HTML maybe it'd help me). You can try it and reach back to see if it worked or if any adjustment is required.

You might want to change your commented lines accordingly. Also about the identifier "#buy_line_items" I'm not sure if it exists in the rendered HTML so you might need to adjust that as well.

Comment: sorry, again this is not working on maa rails' active admin code. 
Instead of using this ajax method, I used rabl gem to get data on Json form by calling an API. So, finally, this rabl gem helps me to get out of that problem. 

Anyway thanks for this wonderful effort. <3

Comment: Hi, no worries. So you have your problem solved, right?
There were a lot of assumptions in my response, so it was likely to fail. I was just trying to give you an idea of what I think could've been a potential approach.

Comment: Yes, my problem has been solved.