# Index in $_POST is not set on php server after http POST

Tags: php, http, post

my Problem is the following:

I have an Apache Server running on an RaspberryPi. I try to make a http POST with paramaters as follows:

http://192.168.178.43/update-led.php/?api_key=tPmAT5Ab3j7F9

Here you can see a picture of it in Postman: [POSTMAN Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtSCZ.png)

However in the php code which gets called in update-led.php file I get the error:

*PHP Notice:  Undefined index: api_key in /var/www/html/update-led.php on line 31*

Here is the Code from the update-led.php file:

```
    $api_key = "";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      if (isset($_POST["api_key"])){// returns false
        $api_key = test_input($_POST["api_key"]);
           if($api_key == $api_key_value) {
               //do something
           }
        }
      } else{
          echo "No Api Key provided"
      }
  }
```

I also get the http result "No Api Key provided" which means the *isset($_POST['api_key'])* command returns *false*.

I can't find the mistake which I am making and the strange thing is, that the api_key is already working in an http GET request with the following Code:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {
   $api_key = test_input($_GET["api_key"]);
   if($api_key == $api_key_value) {
      //do something
   }
}
```

Thank you for your help, i hope I didn't forget any important Information.
Paul

Comment: What do you get if you do `var_dump($_POST);`? I'm wondering if the fact that you have api_key in both GET and POST is confusing it, but that's just a thought.

Comment: You are sending the parameters as GET, to send POST you have to add it under body tab in Postman

Comment: I got it working by changing everything to GET instead of POST. Is there a huge difference between those? what are the benefits of POST?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/504947/1427878

Answer (score -2):

Please remove the `/` after `update-led.php` so the URL is:

```
http://192.168.178.43/update-led.php?api_key=tPmAT5Ab3j7F9
```

Comment: I have read before that this can be the solution on some occasions but for me it didn't help