# Getting Express error via localhost, Error Cannot GET / or GET /sms

Tags: node.js, express, twilio

I'm a huge sneaker head and getting my feet wet in node and express and I'm trying to create an app using Twilio to text me when a certain shoe decreases in price and the shoe is triggered by replying "Track (SKU)" to add it to the database. I have it completely written and when I input "node index.js", it connects to my localhost just fine, but when I input http://localhost:3000/sms, I get Cannot GET /sms. I've been trying to look for a fix by trying to find some videos or if someone has done a similar project to model off of, but no luck. Is anyone familiar with creating Twilio apps with express servers able to help me out? My current index.js is below.

````
const SneaksAPI = require('sneaks-api');
const sneaks = new SneaksAPI();

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

const MessagingResponse = require('twilio').twiml.MessagingResponse;

const Subscribers = [
    {
      "number": 2025550121,
      "styleID": "FY2903",
      "lastResellPrice": 475
    },
    {
      "number": 1234567890,
      "styleID": "DD0587-600",
      "lastResellPrice": 285
    }
  ];

  app.post('/sms', function (req, res) {
    const twiml = new MessagingResponse();
    const SMS = twiml.message();
    const recievedSMS = req.body.Body.toLowerCase().trim();
    const firstWord = recievedSMS.split(" ")[0];

    if (firstWord == 'track'){
    const styleID = recievedSMS.split(" ")[1] || null;
    if(styleID){
        const sneaker = sneaksApiFunctionWrapper(styleID);
        if(!sneaker){
            SMS.body("Sneaker could not be found");
        } else {
            const sub = {        
                "number": req.body.From,
                "styleID": sneaker.styleID,
                "lastResellPrice": sneaker.price
            };
            Subscribers.push(sub);
            SMS.media(sneaker.image);
            SMS.body(`Current lowest price for ${sneaker.name} is $${String(sneaker.price)} at ${sneaker.site}: ${sneaker.url}\nYou will be notified when the price drops. Reply STOP to opt-out of alerts.`);
        }
    }

    } else {
    SMS.body('To start tracking a sneaker, text \"track\" followed by the sneaker ID.');
    }

    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'});
    res.end(twiml.toString());
});

function sneaksApiFunctionWrapper(styleID) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        sneaks.getProductPrices(styleID, function(err, product){
            const lowestResellSite = Object.keys(product.lowestResellPrice).reduce((a, b) => product.lowestResellPrice[a] > product.lowestResellPrice[b] ? a : b);
            const sneaker = {
                name: product.shoeName,
                image: product.thumbnail,
                site: lowestResellSite,
                price: product.lowestResellPrice[lowestResellSite],
                url: product.resellLinks[lowestResellSite],
                styleID: product.styleID
            };
            resolve(sneaker);
        }, (errorResponse) => {
            reject(errorResponse);
        });
    });
 }

app.listen(3000, () => {
   console.log('Express server listening on port 3000');
});```
````

Answer (score 3):

You are using a POST request via `app.post()`, which is different from a GET request. You'll need to submit data via a form or apps like Postman to properly access the POST request.

[When should I use GET or POST method? What's the difference between them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504947/when-should-i-use-get-or-post-method-whats-the-difference-between-them) This gives a solid response.