# Thymeleaf adds question mark to url

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf, java-17

I am currently working on a program using spring boot and thymeleaf and encountered something strange. After submitting a form with th:action="/addEmployee", it does redirect me to the desired view, but the url looks like this 'http://localhost:8050/addEmployee?' instead of this 'http://localhost:8050/addEmployee'. It adds a ? mark even tough I do not want to add pathParams.

View:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Departments</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Department Administration</h1>
        <form method="get" th:action="@{/addEmployee}">
        <div>New Employee: <button type="submit">Add</button></div>
    </form>
  
   </body>
   </html>
```

Controller:

```java
   @Slf4j
   @Controller
   @RequestMapping("/addEmployee")
   @SessionAttributes({"department", "sortOrder"})
   @RequiredArgsConstructor
   public class EmployeeController {

       private final EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;


       @GetMapping
       public String displayForm(Model model, @SessionAttribute("department") Department department,
                              @SessionAttribute("sortOrder") Boolean sortOrder){
           model.addAttribute("department", department);
           model.addAttribute("employee", new Employee());

           return "employeeView";
       }

   }
```

I don't really know what went wrong, since the unexpected question mark did not appear on my previous projects.

Let me know if you need additional code.

Appreciate it!

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using a GET (`method="get"` and `@GetMapping`) instead of a POST here? (even with an empty form).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504947/when-should-i-use-get-or-post-method-whats-the-difference-between-them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because GET carries request parameter appended in the URL string while POST carries request parameter in message body.  You should change your syntax to

`<form method="post" th:action="@{/addEmployee}">`

Your controller should be annotated with `@PostMapping` for this method.

You'll want to follow the examples in the docs more closely as far as the controller.